# Setting up initial data for a WatchOS complication

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

Let's say I have the following scenario:

User installs my WatchOS application on his watch. He never launches it, but he enables the complication. After the complication is enabled and visible, it should show real data.

I am struggling to find a place where to ask for that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `getCurrentTimelineEntry(for:withHandler:)` function in ClockKit. This is where watchOS queries for real data. So, the user doesn't have to launch the actual watchOS application since your complication can act independently by providing data to watchOS.

After activating the watchOS complication, watchOS should automatically call the `getCurrentTimelineEntry(for:withHandler:)` function and will call it again after a given time interval specified in the `getNextRequestedUpdateDate(handler:)` function.

Comment: Yes, but in getCurrentTimelineEntry i need to provide it data. But where exactly should i load this data. I need to communicate it from the iOS app

Comment: You can easily share code between your watchOS application and your complication by adding another class both targets have access to. Move your application's code that queries new information to the new class and call its functions from your complication and your application.

I have to do something similar for [PhoneBattery](https://github.com/marcelvoss/PhoneBattery). You could do something very similar for your application.

Comment: I understand. The question I am asking is that if a user never launches his app, but instead just enables at some time its complication and just then the watchos app is launched in the background. At that point, where should I call the functions of the class you are talking about. (applicationDidFinishLaunching from extensiondelegate doesn't work)

Comment: You shouldn't query for information in the didFinishLaunching function. As its name suggests, it's only called once – right after finishing launching. It doesn't make too much sense to query for information in the ExtensionDelegate.

As I already said: use the getCurrentTimelineEntry(for:withHandler:) function for information fetching and displaying it. You can fetch information there and set it to the text/image providers. This function will be called every time watchOS requests a refresh.

Comment: I want to store the data in an array in extensiondelegate so i can have it in advance when getCurrentTimeline is called

Comment: And later just update the array from the extension when it is needed, using watchconnectivity

Comment: I don't really understand what's your problem here. Access your array from your extension in the getCurrentTimelineEntry function and use its objects for setting up your complication.

There are so many different things that could cause your problem here but you basically don't provide any context which makes it almost impossible to solve it.

Comment: There is no problem accessing the data from getCurrentTimelineEntry. The problem is that the app is not launched directly, so the array is nil initially. I want to initialize the array from extensiondelegate the moment the user enables the complication on his watchface

Comment: The question boils down to: Where can I execute code on the watch side, when the complication is enabled?